# ScrollTop bug jquery On chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

In my website I made sticky header.

It works very well on every browsers but when I test on a Macbook on Chrome there's a bug with the `scrollTop`

I've my main header and a sticky header :

I code this :

```
$(document).on('scroll',function() {    
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 150) {
        $('header:not(.sticky)').hide();
        $('header.sticky').show();
    } else {
        $('header:not(.sticky)').show();
        $('header.sticky').hide();
    }
});
```

When I scroll to 150px it jumps to the top of my page.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in Chrome in Mac Machine

```
  $(document).scroll(()=> {
    if($(this).scrollTop()>= 150) {
      //Your Actions 
    }
    else {
      //Your Actions
    }
  });
```